# Color change when tabPanel in navbarMenu is selected in R shiny

Tags: r, shiny

I'm changing the color of the navbar Page with R shiny.

#### app.R

```
library(shiny)

ui <- shinyUI(
  bootstrapPage(
    navbarPage(title = NULL, id = "navbar",
               navbarMenu("fruits",
                          tabPanel("apple"),
                          tabPanel("orange")
               ),
               navbarMenu("name",
                          tabPanel("jon"),
                          tabPanel("leon")
               ),
               tabPanel("water")
    ),
    
    tags$style(HTML("
        .navbar-default .navbar-brand {color:white;}
        .navbar-default .navbar-brand:hover {color:white;}
        .navbar { background-color:red;}
        .navbar-default .navbar-nav > li > a {color:white;}
        .navbar-default .navbar-nav > .active > a,
        .navbar-default .navbar-nav > .active > a:focus,
        .navbar-default .navbar-nav > .active > a:hover {color:black;background-color:white;}
        .navbar-default .navbar-nav > li > a:hover {color:white;background-color:red;text-decoration}
                  "))
  )
)

server <- function(input, output, session){}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

[image]

I want to change the color when tabPanel is selected in navbarMenu. In the image, "apple" is selected and the background color is blue.
Is it possible to change this to red?
Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add this style to the `tags$style`:

`.dropdown-menu > .active > a {background-color:red;}`

[image]

Comment: And how about to change the color when you click it?

Comment: Could you please clarify @H.berg? Better post your own question with what you get and what you want (you might want to reference it here in the comment)